# Windows Phone 7 : Running thread in the background to sync data

Tags: threadpool

Processes are as follows:

1. App get data via Web Service (WS) methods.
2. Saves them to local NoSQL Database (Sterling).
3. Various pages reads/modifies  data to/from Database to fulfill business logic and adds relevant queue as MessageItem(MessageItems are saved in database) that will be handled by ThreadPool.
4. Now we need to synchronize data to server via Web Service on the basis of MessageItem.

Question:

Can anyone tell me how to keep ThreadPool running all the time and check Queue for message items. Once relevant message item is found (Switch case), then system will call appropriate WS method to for implementation.  Note that there will be always at least one MessageItem in database(It is a business logic)
Many thanks in advance.